# Pandas groupby without dropping data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform a gorupby function on a dataframe without losing any of the other data.

Given the below dataframe:

```
color    name     size
 red      Jim      L
 red      Pam      S
```

I want to return like so:

```
color    name_x    name_y    size_x    size_y
 red       Jim      Pam        L         S
```

I figured just a simple groupby is all I needed to do but for some reason it doesn't work as planned.

`df = df.groupby('color')`

Comment: Check Q 10 in the link

Comment: @WeNYoBen is it not possible to accomplish this with a `groupby()`? I don't understand how to adapt these pivot solutions...

Comment: Then just do groupby + first the unstack

Comment: which is what I came here to try and figure out.

Comment: `df.set_index(['color', df.groupby('color').cumcount()]).unstack()` from cs95